# Inserting python datetime into the mysql table

Tags: python, mysql

I have a Python date like

```
2013-04-04T18:56:21Z
```

I want to store this into my mysql database .

I tried like

```
self.start_at = datetime.strptime(self.start_at.split(".")[0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

But i am getting an error

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: Z
```

PLease tell me how to convert the above date in mysql acceptable format .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance this will work.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> start_at = '2013-04-04T18:56:21Z'
>>> datetime.strptime(start_at , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 18, 56, 21)
```

Are the T & Z characters always in your date format or do they every change?
If the is some variation in these seperator characters, you should do something like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> start_at = '2013-04-04T18:56:21Z'
>>> datetime.strptime(start_at[0:10] + ' ' + start_at[11:19], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 18, 56, 21)
```

Comment: I am getting this  TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: I've amended the code, to clarify the assumptions involved. This should now run as a standalone python 2.* example.